# MongoDB help (relationships)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb

I have a class Foo with an embedded object Bar. Every time a Foo is created, I want its Bar to be created. Bar is initiated by passing variables from Foo. How can I accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using a wrapper lib? If so, what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a before_create hook to auto create your Bar. something like

```
class Foo
  include Mongo....
  attr_reader :new_bar
  before_create :create_bar

  def create_bar
    self.bars << new_bar
  end
end
```

That way you can still validate the bar (using new_bar or whatever you want).

Both MongoMapper and Mongoid have the before_create hook, so you should be fine in either.

Comment: I am using mongoid and want to use embed_one :bar. What should my controllers (Foo and Bar) look like?

Comment: @bar = Bar.new(params[:bar])
@foo.bar = @bar

Comment: Ok. That works great! One more question... Bar extends the Array class. I'd like to call self.bar.method1(var1, var2 .. ) from a method in the Foo model. Essentially, I want to load some default hashes into the Bar < Array that have values dependent upon variables from Foo.

Comment: That should work without any trouble. The array part is a bit off-the-beaten-path ... if you have troubles, you should open a new question with that code.